# ConstraintLayout stealing taps from setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have created an activity that will be used as a screen to display a custom-designed modal. The entire background of this activity will be a 30% black overlay view that should be tappable to dismiss the activity.

Here's a screen of the simple layout:

[image: modal]

In onCreate, I added a setOnClickListener to the overlay:

```
overlayView.setOnClickListener {
        println("tapped")
}
```

The overlay is receiving taps, which is desired, however the white 'modal' view is also receiving taps, which is **not** desired.

As you can see from the component tree in the above screenshot, I'm using a view (overlayView), and then above it, using a ConstraintLayout with a nested textView. I would think that since the white modal is above the overlayView, it would not be receiving taps from overlayView.

**How can I structure / organize my component tree so that I can detect taps from just the overlayView, and not the white modal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, touch events will go "through" views until they find one that actually handles the event. In this case, even though you're tapping on the modal view, the click event will go to the background overlay because the modal view doesn't do anything to intercept the event.

You can solve this by adding a do-nothing click listener to the modal view:

```
modalView.setOnClickListener { }
```

This causes the modal view to receive any click events on it and handle them, stopping them from going "through" to the background overlay view.

Comment: Thank you for that insight, Ben. It's odd to me that you need to set on click listeners to intercept touches from going 'through' views. You would think that a view above another view in the component tree would suffice. But alas, it works as intended!